# click a form button based on the url parameters passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to get this working from a long time now but cannot seem to get it right-
my x.html-

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-4">
        <a href="#add" id="addform" role="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-toggle="modal" style="margin-top:20px">Add Contract</a>
</div>
{% include "a_bs3.html" with form_title="Add :" form_btn="Add" form_id="add" ajax="True" %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var check = location.hash;
    if (check == "trigger") {
        //button trigger even though you do not click on it
        $('#addform').click();
    }
});
</script>
```

I am trying to trigger this 'Add :' form button whenever the url contains a value "trigger" but the button is not auto-clicking, what am I doing wrong?
If you click 'Add :' manually- the form opens up just fine.

Comment: What's your url structure. location.hash represents the things coming after `#` in a url, i.e (http://example.com/#dude)

Comment: yes that is correct- i am passing /abc#trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user jquery `trigger` function. `click` function is used to override the click event. That is not what you want. To trigger an event manually use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var check = location.hash;
    if (check == "#trigger") {
        //triggering click event on #addform
        $('#addform').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickME").click(function(){alert("clicked");});
    
    $("select").change(function(){
       if($(this).val() == 3){
          $('#clickME').trigger('click');
       }
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br/>
<h4>Clickable button</h4>
<button id="clickME">clickME</button>
<br/>
<h4>Select box.When 3 is selected, the click event will trigger</h4>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: updated the code. There is a # before the trigger string. `if (check == "#trigger")`

Comment: check will contain only trigger I think- as mentioned in silickaes comment

Comment: yes "#trigger" worked, I thought location.hash will only pass trigger. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a modular design that will enable you to update your `handler` object with a DOM ID and get an unlimited amount of buttons without conditionals for each and every one

```js
//key: the button id, value: a callback function
// this enables us the reuse functions outside the button scope.
const handlers = {
  foo: () => {
    alert("foo")
  },
  bar: () => {
    alert("bar")
  },
  baz: () => {
    alert("baz")
  }

}

//bunding all our [data-actionable] buttons automatically
let $buttons = $("[data-actionable]");
$buttons.each((i, button) => {
  $(button).on("click", handlers[button.dataset.actionable]);
})

//triggering the handler on change, regardless of the buttons - seperation of concerns.
$(".select").on("change", (e) => {
  let target = e.currentTarget;
  handlers[target.value].apply(null);
});
```

```css
.button {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="foo" data-actionable="foo">foo</button>
<button class="button" id="bar" data-actionable="bar">bar</button>
<button class="button" id="baz" data-actionable="baz">baz</button>

<select class="select">
<option>choose something...</option>
<option value="foo">foo</option>
<option value="bar">bar</option>
<option value="baz">baz</option>


</select>
```